# linux mint cinnamon doesn't recognize camera and microphone in my acer laptop

Tags: linux, linux-mint

#### linux mint cinnamon doesn't recognize camera and microphone in my acer laptop

I installed Cheese and checked but says "no device found".My microphone is also not detecting voice.

Here are the list of commands that i entered and got

#### lspci

```
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:06.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #2 (rev 02)
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 02)
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 02)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 02)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:19.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b3 (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 2050] (rev a1)
0000:2b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
10000:e0:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P SATA AHCI Controller (rev 01)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5411 (rev 01)
```

#### lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c4f Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:4033 Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0000:3825   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

#### dmesg | grep usb

```
[    1.193727] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.193727] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.193727] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.911773] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.911776] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.911777] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.911778] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-69-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.911779] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.912173] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.912175] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.912176] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.912177] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-69-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.912178] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
[    1.914318] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.914320] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.914321] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.914322] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-69-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.914322] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.923290] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.923294] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.923296] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.923297] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-69-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.923298] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.257778] usb 3-6: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.416717] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=3825, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.416740] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.416742] usb 3-6: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[    2.423147] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/0003:0000:3825.0002/input/input6
[    2.423245] hid-generic 0003:0000:3825.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
[    2.423282] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.423283] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.545806] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.732898] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0408, idProduct=4033, bcdDevice= 0.04
[    2.732913] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.732919] usb 3-7: Product: ACER HD User Facing
[    2.732923] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Quanta
[    2.732927] usb 3-7: SerialNumber: 01.00.00
[    2.873755] usb 3-9: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.025573] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0c4f, bcdDevice= 1.65
[    3.025588] usb 3-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.025594] usb 3-9: Product: ELAN:Fingerprint
[    3.025598] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: ELAN
[    3.153748] usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.307958] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0033, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    3.307961] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    6.312308] usb 3-7: Found UVC 1.50 device ACER HD User Facing (0408:4033)
[    6.321741] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    6.345124] usb 3-7: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[    6.348343] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 2858.537115] usb 3-6: reset low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 5272.367905] usb 3-6: reset low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 7668.452457] usb 3-6: reset low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

#### inxi -Fxz

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-69-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.8 Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A515-57G v: V1.08
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ADL model: Ganymede_ADU v: V1.08 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: Insyde v: 1.08 date: 04/25/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 29.7 Wh (56.0%) condition: 53.0/53.0 Wh (100.0%)
    volts: 15.3 min: 15.4 model: PANASONIC AP19B5L status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: 12-core (4-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i5-1240P bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP arch: Alder Lake rev: 3 cache: L1: 1.1 MiB L2: 9 MiB
    L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 599 high: 874 min/max: 400/4400:3300 cores: 1: 446
    2: 630 3: 584 4: 728 5: 597 6: 545 7: 872 8: 443 9: 559 10: 417 11: 599
    12: 874 13: 690 14: 485 15: 470 16: 651 bogomips: 67584
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 0000:00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA107M [GeForce RTX 2050] vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI
    driver: nvidia v: 525.89.02 bus-ID: 0000:01:00.0
  Device-3: Quanta ACER HD User Facing type: USB driver: N/A bus-ID: 3-7:3
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
    direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-69-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 0000:00:14.3
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000
    bus-ID: 0000:2b:00.0
  IF: enp43s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:5
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd
    v: 0.6 bus-ID: 0000:00:0e.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 97.55 GiB (20.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: 2450 MTFDKBA512TFK
    size: 476.94 GiB temp: 30.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 93.31 GiB used: 24.52 GiB (26.3%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 571.9 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.1%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
  ID-3: /home size: 93.31 GiB used: 54.09 GiB (58.0%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 2.2 MiB (0.1%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 373 Uptime: 3h 38m Memory: 15.34 GiB used: 2.73 GiB (17.8%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 Packages: 2692 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: Does https://webcamtests.com/ get any result? (It is recommended in [this Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=365915).)

Comment: Also, I think your camera may be related to '0408:4033 Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing' from your 'lsusb' feedback, as Quanta make ACER's user-facing cameras and I found [your model](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0408-4033)

Comment: I have tried [webcamtests.com] it doesn't detect both camera and mike

Comment: I'm sorry nothing has worked so far, I'm trying to find a solution- all I can tell you for certain is that the lsusb output seems to correlate with your camera, as does Device 3 under Graphics in Fxz. I notice it doesn't list a driver. You can perhaps try a few more camera softwares, like `guvcview` and `VLC`. It says that it should be uvc driver compatible in the previously linked article (so guvc should hopefully work), but I will keep looking for workarounds in the meantime in case this doesn't work!